# Removing All Spaces Except Behind Tag Span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to eliminate all spaces in a textarea, but with the exception, that "in addition to the back of the span tag"

**For example like this:**

`<span>text</span>           <span>text</span>      <span>text</span>
              hello world.. hello world.. hello world.. hello world.. hello world..`

How do I change to be like this automatically using JavaScript or jQuery:

`<span>text</span>           <span>text</span>      <span>text</span>
hello world.. hello world.. hello world.. hello world.. hello world..`

If I use `.replace(/  /g, '')` then all double space will be erased, including those behind the .

**The result is like this:**

`<span>text</span> <span>text</span> <span>text</span>
hello world.. hello world.. hello world.. hello world.. hello world..`

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: What result do you expect actually?

Comment: I want to eliminate double spaced, but not behind the Span tag. Thus, a space that is located before the `<span>` not deleted

Comment: `.replace(/[\s]+<span>/g, ' <span>')` ? It removes all spaces before a `<span>` tag, but forces one. Try your regex [here](https://regex101.com/) if you want something else.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Patrice Bessette - has not worked, and this is just the opposite. I mean is: just eliminating spaces "except behind span"

Comment: So eliminate all spaces **before** the **first** `<span>` only would be correct? Try to remove the `g` after the regex. It means "globally" : .replace(/[\s]+<span>/, ' <span>')

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I think he wants to remove all the spaces except those which are before any `<span>` tags.(as I see in his example, not just one space before the `<span>` but all of the spaces before any `<span>` tag)!!

Comment: @EhsanT: this question is becoming *"unclear"*... It may be all spaces **within** span tags too. Since *"behind span"* may refer to the opening tag after all. I'm voting to close.